VSCode : name of the element on the right of the opened tabs
On VSCode, I would like the element on the right of my opened tabs to have a black background.
There are so much elements I can not find out the name of that element (I also could not find it with the "Developer Tools").
I want the part with a yellow frame on this screenshot :

{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[One Dark Pro]": {
            "editor.background": "#000000",
            "???" : "#000000",
        }
    }
}

Can anyone give me the ??? name, and also explain how to proceed to find it, please ?

there are a finite number of theme colors and most of them are not the right one reading there name, try the other ones and see which one is the jackpot

Yes, that's also how I used to proceed for that.

I finally found it after many tries, I was searching for "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground" :

Edit : The command Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings combined with an image color picker can help finding out the property.
